# How to get pronounce of the word in Google translate api?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

In google translate website, if we translate it shows translation and also pronounce of the word.

[image]

But when I use the Google translate rest API, it only return the translation, I need pronounce of the word same as website.

[image]

**My Rest API**

https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=myApiKey&q=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86&source=ar&target=en

**I may miss something, is any extra parameters there to retrieve these extra information?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating a word from the alphabet of one language to another(get the pronuntiation), is named transliteration and it is not supported by Cloud Translate API yet.

However, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35900102) filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking "**+1**" and "**STAR**" mark to recieve updates on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's weird. It's very simple change, google team still not fixed that issue for 8 years. I don't believe if press +1, star will fix that issue. 

Decided to move Microsoft translate API, It have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same answer.
I haven't found a way to get Pronuntiation with the Google Translate API yet.
However, I found a way to get it through the Python library.
You can use the Python googletrans library.
The code is as follows.

You must use googletrans library 3.1.0a0 to avoid errors.

```
# pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0

from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

SENTENSE = "안녕하세요. 반갑습니다."
LANGUAGE_CODE = translator.detect(SENTENSE).lang

k = translator.translate(SENTENSE, dest=LANGUAGE_CODE)
print(k)
print(k.text)
print(k.pronunciation)
```

```
Output:
Translated(src=ko, dest=ko, text=안녕하세요. 반갑습니다., pronunciation=annyeonghaseyo. bangabseubnida., extra_data="{'translat...")
안녕하세요. 반갑습니다.
annyeonghaseyo. bangabseubnida.
```

Answer (score 0):

gitHub Source for given [gTTS](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS) module:

**1. Install Required Libraries**

```
pip install gTTS
```

**2.  Code Example:**

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

# Text to translate and generate sound for
text_to_translate = "Hello, how are you?"

# Specify the language
language = 'en'  # English

# Create a gTTS object
tts = gTTS(text=text_to_translate, lang=language, slow=False)

# Save the sound file
tts.save("pronunciation.mp3")

# Play the sound
os.system("pronunciation.mp3")  # This is for Windows, for other systems, use appropriate commands
```

This way you can store text to audio and then use 'os' module to play the given audio file.